# How to turn off auto focus to the pair of bracket in GNU Emacs 23

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I installed GNU Emacs 23 on my  Ubuntu 12.10 system. When I write a pair of brackets it will focus the cursor to the open parenthesis.

I have tried to turn off it but I can't find this option. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

The variable I believe you're looking for is `blink-matching-paren`:

> Documentation:
>   Non-nil means show matching open-paren when close-paren is inserted.

So, you can either `M-x customize-variable`, or in your config:
`(setq blink-matching-paren nil)`